# - Logitech macros ! the command doesn't stop while I'm holding down the right mouse button

Tags: lua, macros, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

**https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pX81q-AEn2o7n0rlpvD-GOoKCakMxqO0v8-JXPjtEnA/edit?usp=sharing**

----- - here are all my LUA files

- here are all my Lua files! they are used in LOGitech Ghud . when the macro is active, hold down the right mouse button and press the left mouse button to start the macro ( *you cannot stop the macro while you are holding the right mouse button!) -* I want them to stop when I release the left mouse button

```
    RC_COUNT = #RC_TABLE
    local LastIndex = 1
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then 
        if (LastIndex <= RC_COUNT) then
            i = LastIndex
        else
            i = 1
        end
        while i <= RC_COUNT do
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
                PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
                MoveMouseRelative(RC_TABLE[i].x, RC_TABLE[i].y)Sleep(18)

            else
                LastIndex = i
                break
            end
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
end
```

when i right click my command will use ! and I left click they will continue working

Comment: That's no way c++ code. Remove that tag please!

Comment: Fwiw, it seems like there's something missing at the start of this macro

Comment: Jim, what documentation are you using when programming the macro? G-series Lua API? Which version?

Comment: One detail: `MoveMouseRelative(RC_TABLE[i].x, RC_TABLE[i].y)Sleep(18)` should be on two separate lines. `MoveMouseRelative(RC_TABLE[i].x, RC_TABLE[i].y)` and `Sleep(18)`

Comment: I think you need to post the full lua script in a [mre] and please state what version it is you're working with. The  API and documentation has changed over the years.

Comment: The problem description is unclear. Please: 1) Show the whole script; 2) Specify what you expect the script to do; 3) What the script actually does.

Comment: Jim, since you are new here you may not have expected to get a ton of requests for clarification, but that's not uncommon. It's usually a good idea to post a question when you have time to stick around for 30 minutes to clarify the question. Posting it and leaving it, hoping to have a solution when you check back hours later usually ends in disappointment because the question will likely have been closed so that no answers can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the game, in the "Controls Settings", introduce alternative key for "Shoot" action.  For example, let it be keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.  So, now in the game you can shoot either using Left Mouse Button or using Keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.  Of course, you will use LMB for manual shooting as usually, but your GHub script will use <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Replace these two lines

```
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
```

with the following:

```
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            PressAndReleaseKey("P")
```